# SSL Certificate installation failed while installing pod?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, cocoapods, crashlytics

I get this error while I try to install a podfile which has crashlytics in it as well:

```
Installing Crashlytics (3.3.1)

[!] Error installing Crashlytics
[!] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/1d/2xlstwrn5qd_jf64zznfb2nc0000gn/T/d20150914-12348-1fayiwa/file.zip https://kit-downloads.fabric.io/ios/com.twitter.crashlytics.ios/3.3.1/com.twitter.crashlytics.ios-default.zip --create-dirs

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally solved it with this on Project Folder:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: This worked for me as a workaround. The issue was with my openssl install.

Comment: This worked for me too. But what's the core issue. Is this a fix or just a workaround?

Comment: works for my issue too, what happened? is this safe/secure?

Comment: can you please explain how to do this

Comment: Go to a project directory from Terminal, and just copy paste the above command.

Comment: worked for me too. Just go to the project directory and hit this command on the terminal.

Comment: this is a huge security issue as SSL is being disabled with the command. How is this the accepted answer?